# Start a new systemd session with a shell

Tags: systemd

When signing into a user with gnome-session, a user slice is created, the user dbus session is started, and all user processes run inside that slice.

If I'm signed into a system with a shell as root, how can I "login" to another user, running the shell inside a user session as described above? Aka, how can I sign in with a shell rather than a graphical session?

Note: if I use "login myuser" it works, creating the slice. But systemctl --user returns an error indicating the user dbus is not running.

Answer (score -1):

I asked this question after:

- docker exec with a user id
- sudo bash
- su - myuser

This doesn't work, because the original tty was already attached to that user without going through PAM.

The systemd user instance is started by the systemd pam extension. Therefore, if I instead:

- docker exec with root
- su - myuser

The systemd user unit and systemd --user and the dbus instance are all started correctly, because systemd / pam now recognizes that I'm switching user accounts and creating a new session.